# apache and node express with node rewrites

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess, express

I have the following problem:

I have an apache serving files under url.com/ and url.com/a

I also have a node-express server listening on port 3000, which is not publicly accessable.

Now, I would like to be able to access the node server for any url like url.com/b/.

My hosting company and google referred me to using .htaccess rewrites like so under url.com/, but it does not work:

`RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)b(.*)$ https://url.com:3000/b/$1`

Does the port need to be publicly accessable for the mod_rewrite approach to work?
What is the proper way to set something like this up?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, since i deployed on a managed virtual server, i wasnt able to use Elvis' solution, modifying the httpd.conf file.

I ended up using this solution, modifying the .htaccess file in the folder public_html/b:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost:3000/$1 [P]`

Answer (score 0):

Try `mod_proxy`:

`<Location /b>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
</Location>`